# Getting String Pattern

Tags: java, regex

i have an example of the following string (all this in one string).

```
6 x 9 + 4 = 58.0 

</br> 58.0  markers cost $33.

</br> 33/ 58.0  = 0.5689655172413793 

<br>Each marker cost $0.5689655172413793 .

<br> 0.5689655172413793  x 9 = 5.120689655172414 

<br>Each eraser cost $5.120689655172414 

<br> (5.120689655172414  x 3) +  (0.5689655172413793  x 10) = 21.051724137931036 

<br>The total cost is $21.051724137931036 .
```

I want to remove all the other stuff and get only the mathematical expressions..

```
6 x 9 + 4 = 58.0
33/ 58.0  = 0.5689655172413793 
0.5689655172413793  x 9 = 5.120689655172414 
(5.120689655172414  x 3) +  (0.5689655172413793  x 10) = 21.051724137931036
```

I have tried the regex pattern to remove all the other stuff but it get splitted indvidually one char by one char.

```
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+|[\\+\\-*/=()])").matcher(qalist.get(i).getFullsol());

         while(matcher.find())
         {
             System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
         }
```

Anyone can help? :)

Encountered Problem

```
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?[^=:a-wyz]+)=\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher("The expression is (9 * 1) -1 = 8 ");
```

I will get :

Expression: 9 * 1) -1

Answer: 8

Wonder whats wrong..

```
Whole expression: (5.120689655172414  x 3) +  (0.5689655172413793  x 10) = 21.051724137931036
Expression: 5.120689655172414  x 3) +  (0.5689655172413793  x 10)
Answer: 21.051724137931036
```

Comment: Are the `<br>` tags in the string too?

Comment: Yup Jerry... the <br> is in the string too. :)

Comment: What is about read char by char and let thru all but letters, <, >, $ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use this pattern:

```
\\(?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?[^=a-wyz]+=\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW9tX5)

`\\(?` is to match a potential opening parenthesis

`\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` is to match a number, integer or floating.

`[^=a-wyz]+=` will match almost anything except equal sign and letters (`x` will match however) except letters until it reaches an equal sign.

`\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` is to match the result of the expression, consisting of potential spaces, and a number (integer or floating).

Comment: Hi Jerry your codes works wonders for most of my answer templates. However i have one answer template that looks like this.

I have edited from my post

Comment: @rushh05 I cannot see the answer template :(

Comment: To Jerry...I have a template that looks like this...
It just seem to have the extra 1:, 2:, 3: infront.

How do i remove it? :)

    Step1:7 - 1 = 6     
    Step2: 6/7*6 = 306     
    Step 3: 306 - 19 = 287

Comment: And the answer shows as.....  1:  7 - 1 = 6
    2: 6/7*6 = 306
    3: 306 - 19 = 287

Comment: @rushh05 Oh! You can add `:` to the negated class! Change `[^=a-wyz]` to `[^=:a-wyz]`. If you encounter similar problems, you could add characters which shouldn't be there inside.

Comment: Sorry Jerry...i always have problem editing my question as they always prompt me that i have indented an unformatted code...sorry for putting the template in the comment

Comment: @rushh05 Oh that's okay, don't worry :) It wasn't a long line, so it's not that hard to read! Did the addition of `:` in the character class work?

Comment: Thanks Jerry..so far it works..Im gonna test further with some other templates.. thanks for the time taken to help :)

Comment: @rushh05 Great! Let me know if you have any other problems :)

Comment: Hi Jerry i an trying to get the string before and after the equal sign because i want to get the expression and answers separately. I tried to refer to your regex and took the part until it takes everything till the equal sign. But I am having error :( ... My syntax could be wrong.. :/

Comment: @rushh05 How about using capture groups? See the [demo](http://ideone.com/5TrjyK).

Comment: @Jerry..wow that is more concise and all in one..thanks alot Jerry.. :) been a great help. Happy New Year!

Comment: Hi Jerry..sorry to disturb u again :/ ... I have an expression (9 * 1) -1 = 8 inside the string .. using the current expression regex I will get ..  9 *) -1 = 8  .. the ( is missing infront. :( I tried to add on but in vain. Do I have to add ( in front of the regex?

Comment: @gonggong I'm not sure how that is happening. [It seems to be working fine?](http://regex101.com/r/nB0qY1)

Comment: I have put the problem encountered in my edit. Hmm I am baffled too whats wrong..

Comment: Hi Jerry, oh yeah I just notice that the demo u did oso had that error. LOL. I just noticed it too..

Comment: @gonggong Ohhhh! Now I understand. I had put the `(` a character too late in the regex. `\\(?(` at the start should be `(\\(?` instead. [There we go](http://ideone.com/U55IGM).

Comment: Hi Jerry..oh wow! It works! Thanks a million again kind man. :)

Comment: @gonggong Great! I'm sorry I messed it up last time ^^;

Comment: Hi Jerry..haha fret not. U have been a great help to me...kudos to you... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String l : str.split("</?br>")) {
        l = l.trim();
        if (!l.isEmpty() && !l.matches(".*[a-zA-Z&&[^x]].*")) {
            sb.append(l).append("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
([()\s\d.x*+/-]+\s*=\s*[\d.]+)
```

Comment: I got error when i put it as ("([()\s\d.x*+/-]+\s*=\s*[\d.]+)")

Comment: Its okay M42. :) thanks for the effort. Appreciate it :)